# Ruby: Fastest way to test if any number from a list is in a list of ranges?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

One possible way to check if at least one number from a list is in one range of other list is like the following:

```
# Input example:
# numbers = [123, 345, 567]
# ranges =[(1..10), (60..80), (200..400)]
def is_in(numbers, ranges)
  numbers.each do |n|
    ranges.each do |r|
      return true if r.include?(n)
    end
  end
  false
end
```

What is the fastest way for each one of this cases:

1. Only numbers list is big
2. Only ranges list is big
3. Both are big

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your number array is large AND ordered, you could speed up the range coverage check from O(N) complexity to O(logN) using Ruby 2.0's new binary search [`Array#bsearch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) method.

```
class Range
  def fast_cover_any?(ordered_arr)
    lo = first
    probe = ordered_arr.bsearch {|x| x >= lo}
    probe && exclude_end? ? probe < last : probe <= last
  end
end

ranges.any? { |r| r.fast_cover_any?(numbers) }
```

Comment: @fotanus I notice you accepted my answer -- does that mean you did a benchmark and saw substantial improvement?  If so I'd love to see the results, perhaps you could update your question with benchmark results and a link to a gist of the benchmark?

Answer (score 1):

```
ranges =[(1..10), (60..80), (200..400)]

numbers = [123, 700, 567]
numbers.any?{|x| ranges.any? {|y| y.include? x}} #=> false

numbers = [123, 400, 567]
numbers.any?{|x| ranges.any? {|y| y.include? x}} #=> true
```

Using `ordered list`:

```
ranges =[(1..10), (60..80), (200..400)]

numbers = [123, 300, 567]
p numbers.sort.any?{|y| ranges.sort_by(&:first).bsearch{|x| x.include? y}} #=> true

numbers = [123, 700, 567]
p numbers.sort.any?{|y| ranges.sort_by(&:first).bsearch{|x| x.include? y}} #=> false
```

Comment: @ElKamina If you have any point to mention not to be fast,please fire.  As looking at the OP's code,I think `any?` and `include?` is better choice.

Comment: It looks like worst case complexity of your code is o(mn). Can you do better?

Comment: @ElKamina please check now.

Comment: You are close, but your complexity is still O(mn). You need to use binary search.

Comment: @ElKamina and what ruby structures uses binary search? It is not possible that there isn't one.

Comment: @fotanus Plain old Array does [in Ruby 2.0](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch).

Comment: @steenslag in my code how can I improve using bsearch, could you advice?

Comment: @ElKamina please check or tell if any more improvement if possible?

Comment: You've gone from O(NM) to O(NlogN MlogM) time.  That's not faster. You seem to be misusing [`bsearch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) too. The block has to correlate with the ordering.  I don't believe `include?` meets the necc invariant to guide a search over an ordering of `ranges.sort_by(&:first)`.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is store one of the data structures in a organized structure and search the other list's elements.

Assume you have two lists x and y with lengths m and n respectively.

If m << n: sort x and and find elements from y in the sorted list

If m >> n: sort y and and find elements from x in the sorted list

If they are of same size choose any of them to sort.

How to organize ranges:
Sort the list using start of each range. If two ranges overlap merge them. At the end you will have a list of non-overlapping ranges sorted according to start of the range.

Comment: Actually would be faster in speed to just extend the ranges and use a hash, however memory would explode. Thanks, that was an answer more like this I was looking for. Let's see if @Priti knowledge of ruby can help.